# "Truest of friends" vs. "truest friends"

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, superlatives

The following are three authentic examples from Google Books:

> 1. Both women experience loss, from men to dreams, but through it all
>    they remain **the truest of friends** for 50 amazing years.
> 2. Loyalty makes the wolf a good member of the pack, the dog **the truest
>    of friends**, the savage a good member of the band, the tribe.
> 3. We are sharing with **a truest of friends** and there must also be time to
>    reflect and unburden ourselves, to voice our hopes, disappointments,
>    regrets, and to savor his companionship.

I'm wondering what role the preposition ***of*** plays in these examples. Why not just say "truest friends" instead?

Are these two constructions interchangeable? Any contextual nuances implied?

Comment: Same meaning implied I reckon, but there's a smallest poetic effect to the usage in question. :)

Comment: 3) should be "*the* truest of friends".

Answer (score 2):

Your **truest of friends** is the **most** truest of your friends, it implies the top of a hierarchy, whereas a group of people can be your **truest friends**:

> My **truest friends** are the ones I knew in grammar school.

Your **truest of friends** is your **very** best friend.

> Of my truest friends, David is my **truest of friends**.

Though this does sound a bit strange because of the meaning of **true**.
If you substitute closest, it might be clearer:

> I've known my **closest friends** for a long time.
>   I've know my **closest of friends**, David, since we were 4 years old.

Comment: He is not asking for the definition, but on the grammatical role of the "of" in the phrase.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31810)

Comment: Does not *implies the top of a hierarchy* answer what **of** does, especially in light of the proposed alternative?

Comment: @Peter user3169 says 3) should be "the truest of friends". Do you agree?

Comment: @KinzleB It could be either "a" or "the", the context is slightly ambiguous, is it a group of "truest of friends" which are sharing their thoughts with each other, or are they sharing their thoughts with a single member of their group of "truest of friends"? "The 10 of us are *the truest of friends* and being part of the group, he is *a truest of friends (a truest friend)*". If you were to say "He is *the truest of friends*" it would refine the scope of the group since " the truest" is a superlative. The #3 sentence could be read either way depending on what the speaker wants to convey.